# My wife is lost, my GPS is lost. Where are we?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

"Darling, can you please turn on the GPS?" I asked my wife.

"Hang on, I know exactly where we are", she replied.

"Can you, for once, listen to me?"

She ignored my remark, immersed in the reading of the map. This was not the first time we were going on a trip, and this was definitely not the first time we were having a heated discussion because of this! Argh, in moments like these, I hate her for not listening to me. Especially when we are in a city we don't know!

"Seriously, you never knew how to read a map, turn on the damn thing".

"Hey, chill. Look, you just have to turn right, here."

I turned right.

"To the right, again, don't miss it".

I turned right again, but I smelt something was wrong.

"Ok, seems that you have to turn ri..."

"Again?! We're back on the same road! You can't read a map, I already told you!"

She fulminated, and turned on the GPS (yes, she should have done that in the first place, right?).

> In 100 meters, turn right. Then, in 100 meters, turn left.

"Ah, you see? It's not making us going round in circles, at least!"

I turned right, then left.

> In 100 meters, turn left. Then, in 100 meters, turn right.

"Wait", my wife said, "aren't we going on the same road again?"

"No, there are roadworks, we're just avoiding them."

> In 100 meters, turn right. Then, in 100 meters, turn left.

"Sorry, honey, but your GPS is broken", she told me. "We're back on the road parallel to our initial road, and there were not any roadworks!"

"Yes, ok, this is strange. I'm sure there's an explanation, maybe there's... traffic jam?"

"Traffic jam? For 100 meters? Are you kidding me?"

I stayed silent, awaiting for the next instructions from my GPS, hoping it was not broken.

> In 100 meters, turn left. Then, in 100 meters, turn right.

"Ok, maybe it's broken!"

"Ah, you see! Your 'modern' instrument is as bad as me!"

"Stop talking nonsense, and take the map".

I followed the instructions of the GPS nonetheless.

"Ok, now, turn right on the next cross-road", indicated my wife.

I turned right.

"No, not this one, sorry. Just turn around."

I turned around, and this time I went right on the good roa...

"NO! Darling, concentrate please! This is a deadend!"

I mumbled, but that was my fault this time. So I turned around again, and took the next road on the right.

---

Though this question doesn't make sense at first glance, can you guess **where are my wife and I**?

Comment: Sounds like you're in the Costco parking lot.

Comment: You're in a European city with a lot of one-way streets.

Comment: Your first "back on the same road" scenario would typically need 4 right turns if you're in a regular grid. Did you intentionally only have three?

Comment: @IanMacDonald You need 3 to be back on the same road, but 4 to go in the same direction that the one at the beginning. But you're right, we'll consider the case where you're back on the same road, taking the same direction as the beginning.

Comment: @IAmInPLS 3 to be back if its square shaped streets as NY but europe has curvy roads so who knows where you are after a few turns xD  *real roads have curves*! XD

Comment: Did you hijack the [Magic School Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_School_Bus) and now you're driving around on some kind of [inverter gate](https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/06/adem/engin/e77vlsi/lab3/logic_inverter.gif)?

Comment: @IAmInPLS I'm not sure I follow. Let's say you're initially heading N on road 1. Your first right turn heads you E on road 2. Your second right turn heads you S on road 3. Your third right turn heads you W on road 4. Road 4 and road 1 are not the same, nor are W and N.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, that's assuming that all the turns are perfectly $90^\circ$.  It's possible that there could be three streets that intersect to form a triangle.  Or the roads could be curved.

Comment: @IanMacDonald After your third turn, you'll join the road 1 via road 4, at the crossroad. So, 3 turns. But I told you that anyway, in this puzzle, you will take the road 1 again.

Comment: You are stuck in that crazy stairs painting of M. C. Escher aren't you!?

Comment: [comment directed outwards in general] What's with all the downvotes for incorrect guesses?  Is that really how this site rolls?  Seems like it'd be discouraging for participation unless someone was absolutely sure of their answer or didn't care about getting needlessly dinged on rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT

> After mapping their whole trip (and discussing some details in the chat room), I ended up with a drawing that spell out the word PSE.
>
> Here is the drawing:
>
>  [image]
>
>  The letters are spelt in the way they're driving, so P, then S, and finally E.
>  So, they are driving in PSE: **Puzzling Stack Exchange**! (Yeah, strange place to drive, eh?)

Comment: Oooh. You are definitely on the good way, however you got the wrong letters somewhat. Feel free to add a drawing!

Comment: (Well, I admit the instructions are not very clear on purpose ;-) )

Comment: @IAmInPLS I tried drawing it in paint. Forgive the mediocre quality. I am unsure about the begining (3 or 4 right turn) and the end(3 back and forth)

Comment: I am also unsure if "I followed the instructions of the GPS nonetheless." implies that there is a few extra turns that were done until the wife reached for the map again.

Comment: The end is good, but the beginning is a bit wrong. Let's say, they were alreay driving for 100 meters before turning right first.

Comment: @IAmInPLS I  think I already drive up 100m before my first right, but if I do add another one at the beginning, the O will become a P which would give ESSP or EESSP which make no sense to me... Maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51279/discussion-between-iaminpls-and-stack-reader).

Comment: Dude, that looks like PSE backwards... Although, I don't understand how they would drive in PSE..

Answer (score 4):

I know a solution is already accepted, but I have a picture that I think matches the description of the trip a little better.
From it we can see you are indeed

> driving in the land of **PSE**.
>  Of course, at the end we see you drive away...
>  **["On second thought, let's not go to PSE. It is a silly place."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQCArh_R9dY)**

**The pic:**

> [image]

Initially driving "north" (doesn't matter but all directions relative to this starting direction and road) - from bottom of diagram up to "1".

**The trip:**
**1.**  I turned right.
  "To the right, again, don't miss it".
**2.** I turned right again, but I smelt something was wrong.
**3.** "Ok, seems that you have to turn ri..."  (I assume we make this turn.)
**->** "Again?! We're back on the same road!"  (Yes, we are.)
  `In 100 meters, turn right. Then, in 100 meters, turn left.`
**->** "Ah, you see? It's not making us going round in circles, at least!"
**4.** I turned right, ...
**5.** ... then left.
  `In 100 meters, turn left. Then, in 100 meters, turn right.`
(Doesn't say we do, but I assume we follow these directions, so --)
**6.** (Turn left.)
**7.** (Turn right.)
**->** "Wait", my wife said, "aren't we going on the same road again?"  (Yes. We are.)
**->** "No, there are roadworks, we're just avoiding them." (Apparently, roadworks between **4** and **7**)
  `In 100 meters, turn right. Then, in 100 meters, turn left.`
(Doesn't say we do, but I assume we follow these directions, so --)
**8.** (Turn right.)
**9.** (Turn left.)
**->** "Sorry, honey, but your GPS is broken", she told me. "We're back on the road parallel to our initial road, and there were not any roadworks!"  (Yup)
  `In 100 meters, turn left. Then, in 100 meters, turn right.`
**->** I followed the instructions of the GPS nonetheless.
**10.** (Turn left.)
**11.** (Turn right.)
**->** "Ok, now, turn right on the next cross-road", indicated my wife.
**12.** I turned right.
**->** "No, not this one, sorry. Just turn around."
**13.** I turned around, ...
**14.** and this time ... [implies he continues as if **12** didn't happen: so turn right, resume original course]
**15.** ... I went right on the good roa...
**->** "NO! Darling, concentrate please! This is a deadend!"   (Yup)
**16.** [...] So I turned around again, ...
**17.** ... [and again turn right, resume original course]
**18.** ... and took the next road on the right.

There are multitudinous turns in the accepted answer's trip diagram that are not indicated at all in the story, so I wanted to make a diagram that actually agrees with what the story says and implies the driver did.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> You are a high school student on spring vacation, practicing improv for drama class, and just learning to drive

Wait, what?

> You're taking your time driving and practicing your improv talent with an actor playing your wife; only during a mild spring break would you be able to take this much time on the road (too risky to do on icy roads during winter break, and you wouldn't be thinking about school over summer vacation). And, you figure, why *not* do this to practice turning as you near your driver's license test?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by stack reader I gave my try on the puzzle:

> [image]
>  I mapped the turns with guessing how long some of them were (aside from the 100 meters fixed turns, however we do not know how long it did take for the GPS to announce to turn in 100m?)
>  What resolved is the letters WNNP, could be also others, however those letters somewhat hint at my current tip of the answer:
>
> They are in **Winnipeg**

Answer (score 0):

You're driving

> on a cube with length, base and heigth 100 m

Explanation:

> Suppose that you always turn in the center of a face. Turning right thrice means you're on the same line and in the same direction again.
>
>  Turning right, left, left, right, right, left brings you on the same line (around the cube) but in the opposite direction.
>
>  I'm not sure about the dead end thing, though.

Comment: Not at all :-).

Answer (score 0):

you are

> in space

Explanation :

> the movement done with the car is similar to the one done with the spool while sewing, with a back and forth at the end to close the string. Another name for the spool used for sewing is **shuttle**, hence you are in space.

Comment: Wow, a long shot! Unfortunately, there's not much lateral-thinking here.